# Selenium WebDriver - handle StaleElementReferenceException (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I am writing Python code using Selenium which clicks on a button on a web page. After the button is clicked, the button changes to something else. My code works perfectly fine, but Selenium is misinterpreting this as a problem. I'm attempting to ignore the exception and move on but nothing I've tried has worked.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'SomeButtonText')]").click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
```

What can I do to ignore the exception and move on? My code WORKS with what I'm trying to do, but after a couple seconds, the exception is thrown.

```
Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

Here is the extremely messy information from the Ubuntu Terminal:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 107, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9351)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmp24d8CK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8978)
    at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///tmp/tmp24d8CK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12019)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp24d8CK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp24d8CK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp24d8CK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Comment: Could you post the complete traceback and on which line an error is thrown? Thanks

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for your reply. I posted the information from the console but I don't know if that will help much.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, on which line in your code the error happens?

Comment: @alecxe I found the bug in my code. Very simple mistake. The line at which I was clicking the button was at the end of a loop. The line was actually executing correctly and went back to the top of the loop where another stale reference problem was happening. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Sure, please post it as an answer and accept as soon as you can to resole the topic. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

The code here:

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'SomeButtonText')]").click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
```

Was executing at the end of a for loop. I completely missed the fact that it returned to the beginning of the loop where I had a separate problem with a Stale reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because 
Html is loading and client is still receiving updates from server

how ever i made a solution for problem  you can simply use my custom wait before clicking . call this function

```
 public static void waitForElementPresent(final By by, int timeout,WebDriver driver)
```

After this if you are using browser other then chrome then call Scroll to that object this would fix you problem Code

```
public static void waitForElementPresent(final By by, int timeout,WebDriver driver) { 

        waitForPageLoad(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,40).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class); 
        /*  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){ 
            @Override 
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) { 
              WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(by); 
              return element != null && element.isDisplayed(); 
            } 
          }); */
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
          WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
          wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));

        }
    //wait for page to laod 
    public static void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver) {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
    }
```